# token renewal operation failed due to timeout adal.js

Tags: adal.js

I mentioned the configuration above.

```
var config = {
            instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
            tenant: 'xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
            clientId: clientId,
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // to support IE
            extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
            endpoints: endpoints,
            anonymousEndpoints: [
                "xxxxx/header.html",
                "xxxxx/footer.html",
                "xxxx/Home.html"
            ]
        };
        adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(config, $httpProvider);
```

Issue: sometimes we are getting token renewal operation failed exception. 
Please suggest us how to fix this issue. this is major blocking issue for us.

Comment: Please provide detailed error logs so that people understand better the issue.

Comment: It is helpful if you can provide a demo to help to reproduce this issue.

Comment: User logged into the application and performed some operation and kept it idle for 15 to 20 minutes. again he is trying to perform some operation and call is being made to adal for token renewal but adal is not responding with the new token and application is getting freeze. for time being we are redirecting the user to home screen and making fresh adal request for the authentication. Please help us how to renew the token without redacting user to login page.

Comment: What's kind of token you are referring, id_token or access_token? And both the expired time should be 1 hour by default, did you custom the lifetime of token? And without the code, it is difficult to narrow this issue.